# Adding from text file to listview first items just gets added twice

Tags: vb.net

So I have a listview with two columns: Objects, and Prices.
I'm trying to have a saving/loading system so that I could save the items in the listview to a text file, but when I try to load from a text file it just puts the first object and price as many times as there are items.

The code is:

```
    Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
    rtb.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\JohnDoe\OneDrive\Desktop\My Visual Basic Program 'calculator' Files\nslm.txt")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each line As String In rtb.Lines
        If line = "^^" Then
            Dim item As New ListViewItem
            item.Text = rtb.Lines(i + 1)
            item.SubItems.Add(rtb.Lines(i + 2))
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Else
        End If
    Next
```

And the text file is:

1. ^^
2. Healthy Apple
3. 290
4. ^^
5. Rotten Apple
6. 500

And it displays Healthy Apple and 290 twice, instead of displaying it as it should be. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increment of variable i is missing; it is always using values (0+1) and (0+2).